# kate: Output external tool stdout to embedded terminal

Tags: shell-script, terminal, kate

I currently have set up several shortcuts that run external tools. Some of those tools generate some kind of summary. I would like to make that summary easier to read at a glance. The standard terminal features are good for that, since I already have a library for my kind of ANSI escape styling.

But external commands can only be configured to output to a separate output panel/sidebar.

I know the embedded terminal is a separate module, making this lack understandable… but in the end it’s all just processes and code (and data). …

So what’s the easiest way to have my external command output to the embedded terminal?
Write to its output buffer? Autorun a process in it (e.g. via .bashrc) that will listen for and receive data via a named pipe to display there? Spawn an external terminal window with smart placement instead?
Ideally I would alter the code of the *external commands* and *embedded terminal* functionality, to add an “embedded terminal” option to the dropdown of choices for what to do with the output. But it’s a bit much to learn coding KDE applications just to make a small change.

Does anyone know a better solution?